# How can I inverse matched result of the pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my string:

```
Organization 2
info@something.org.au more@something.com market@gmail.com single@noidea.com 
Organization 3
headmistress@money.com head@skull.com
```

Also this is my pattern:

```
/^.*?@[^ ]+|^.*$/gm
```

As you see in the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kN3eR5/2), the pattern matches  this:

```
Organization 2
info@something.org.au 
Organization 3
headmistress@money.com
```

---

**My question:** How can I make it inverse? I mean I want to match this:

```
more@something.com market@gmail.com single@noidea.com
head@skull.com
```

How can I do that? Actually I can write a new *(and completely different)* pattern to grab expected result, but I want to know, Is *"inverting the result of a pattern"* possible?

Comment: Anything stopping you from reversing the string and then just using the original regex?  Maybe you could use a lookbehind of some sort but what would be the point?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The point is matching everything which isn't matched by the pattern.

Comment: Upvoted.  Maybe @Wiktor will know the answer to this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks .. Yeah Wiktor is really knowledgeable in *regex* tag. Waiting for him `;-)`

Comment: @Shafizadeh You can't do that with "pure" JavaScript regex, not for the general case (you could with other flavors like PCRE though [demo in PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/nR6pV6/1))

Comment: @Mariano Ah I see. thx

Comment: On a side note, I'd use `String.split()` instead of `.replace()` to be able to separate matches.

Comment: @Mariano Ah ok .. good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't believe there is a way to directly inverse a Regular Expression but keeping it the same otherwise.

However, you could achieve something close to what you're after by using your existing RegExp to replace its matches with an empty string:

```
var everythingThatDidntMatchStr = str.replace(/^.*?@[^ ]+|^.*$/gm, '');
```

Comment: Yup .. removing matched value from the original value gives me what I'm looking for. Thx +1. Just I'm curious about how I can do that by pure regex.

Comment: Glad to help. Note that my answer is still just a single, pure regex line, just using `RegExp.replace` instead of `RegExp.match`.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the matches from first `RegExp` by using `Array.prototype.forEach()` to replace matched `RegExp` with empty string using `String.ptototype.replace();

```
var re = str.match(/^.*?@[^ ]+|^.*$/gm);
var res = str; 
re.forEach(val => res = res.replace(new RegExp(val), ""));
```

Comment: Yup .. removing matched value from the original value gives me what I'm looking for. Thx +1. Just I'm curious about how I can do that by pure regex.

Comment: What do you mean by "pure regex"?

Comment: I mean doing that in [here](https://regex101.com/r/kN3eR5/2#javascript) .. I want to match exactly what is into substitution box.

Comment: @guest271314 This can fail in some situations.. You're not escaping the match result when it's used in the 2nd regexp constructor. Consider the following **[example](https://jsfiddle.net/7vamrdcx/)**.. Also, the expression is supposed to match at `^`, only, but `replace` would remove the matched text from the whole subject.